# How to limit ext4 filenames to only those filenames legal in FAT?

Tags: filenames, ext4

The `ext4` filesystem allows some characters that FAT does not allow, such as `:`.

This has caused me much grief in the past when trying to move files, especially as [KDE will delete such files](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165365) instead of failing the move.

Is there any way to configure `ext4` to disallow such characters?

Right now I am using an up-to-date Kubuntu, but I would like to know the solution in the general sense, for any Linux-based OS.

Comment: It might be possible to hack this with [convmsfs](http://fuse-convmvfs.sourceforge.net/) by hacking an encoding for iconv that only has characters that are valid on FAT.

Comment: Thank you Gilles. That project might be a step in the right direction, even though it does note quite prevent the characters from being used in the first place. If you convert the comment to an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I don't consider this an answer, just a possible first step that may lead to an answer. If you get something to work using convmvfs or a patched version of it, please describe what worked for you in an answer.

Comment: Yes, it is a first step, but I was quite stuck on the first step! Actually it will be some time before I have the opportunity to implement this solution, but when I get around to it I will post back detailed steps. Thanks, Gilles!